# How to write a list to file as one row and without quotes in R

Tags: r, file, list, quotes

I am trying to write a list to file as one row and without quotes in R.

Content of the list is:

```
 [1] "X4775495036_J" "X4775495036_F" "X5147722015_F" "X5067554009_F"
 [5] "X5067554063_B" "X4954590047_A" "X5067554063_G" "X5067554009_L"
 [9] "X5147722015_D" "X5511045011_D" "X5067554063_A" "X4805447025_F"
[13] "X5455362015_K" "X4805447025_L" "X5147722015_B" "X5067554009_G"
[17] "X5147722014_K" "X5067554063_H" "X5147722009_G" "X5067554008_H"
[21] "X5067554054_H" "X4805447016_K" "X5147722014_E" "X4954590051_K"
[25] "X5067554008_E" "X5147722015_H" "X5147722009_H" "X5067554063_D"
[29] "X5147722015_A" "X5511045022_E" "X5067554054_I" "X5067554063_J"
[33] "X5067554007_F" "X4775495036_E" "X4775495036_H" "X4805447025_H"
[37] "X5067554009_I" "X4805447025_K" "X4954590051_C" "X4805447025_E"
[41] "X5067554063_E" "X5147722009_J" "X5067554054_C" "X5067554054_G"
[45] "X4805447016_I" "X5455362015_B" "X5067554009_H" "X5147722014_A"
[49] "X4775495036_I" "X5067554063_L" "X5455362015_J" "X4954590047_J"
[53] "X5067554009_A" "X4954590051_D" "X5455362015_I" "X5511045011_E"
[57] "X5147722014_F"
```

I want something like this (all elements in one row):

```
X4775495036_J X4775495036_F X5147722015_F X5067554009_F ...
```

I have tried with `write.table`, `write` but with no result.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you don't have a list, you have a character vector.

```
cat(your_vector, "\n", file="your_file.txt")
```

The `"\n"` is an optional newline at the end.

Comment: Sometimes it could be so simple. A simple `cat` would be enough. I was influenced by the mention of `write` by OP.

Comment: This works but after a small change.. I called it with `cat(unlist(my_list), "\n", file="your_file.txt")` .. unlist here is necessary I found.. because otherwise it tells me `argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'` ..

Comment: @hong-ooi if you insert unlist in your command I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ncolumns` argument of write:

```
n <- LETTERS[1:10] # create example values
write(n, "letters.txt", ncolumns=length(n))
```

Or you could concatenate your names before:

```
nc <- paste0(n, collapse=" ")
write(nc, "letters.txt")
```